# How to see output of a running program over ssh

Tags: ssh, stdout

I use debian 6 on an embedded system which is supposed to run a program called `pilot`. The OS is configured to login as root without asking password (there is no monitor nor keyboard connected). After login, `pilot` will run automatically.

I need to see std output of the `pilot`. I'm connecting with ssh over wireless.

Answer (score 5):

Execute the `pilot` under `screen` or similar tool or with stdout and stderr redirected to pipe to tool similar to Apache's `rotatelogs`.

Comment: Can't figure out how do I do that...

Comment: How is the `pilot` program started on the embedded system? Can you modify the way it is being executed?

Comment: If you can't figure out what launches `pilot`, then move the binary to one side (e.g. `pilot.real`) and insert a script named `pilot` that contains `exec screen pilot.real "$@"`.

Comment: I need to see output after pilot is started. Pilot is started in when bashrc in loaded.